# Dynamically copy a configured rich text box in C#?

Tags: c#

In C#, is it possible to dynamically create a rich text box, configure that box with a number of properties (font, size etc.), then dynamically create copies of *that* box, so that newly-created duplicates already possess the required properties? I'm coming from VB6 (don't laugh), where control arrays made this sort of thing easy. I have searched here and elsewhere for an answer, but no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, yes you can, but you'd have to clone it. C# provides a method for that, but it likely does a shallow cloning. You'll need a deep and complete cloning of all levels.

It is much easier and a better approach to create a factory function. You call it and it creates a new control, sets the properties, and then returns the object fully initialized. Something like this:

```
public RichTextBox RichTextBoxFactory() {
    RichTextBox rb = new RichTextBox();
    rb.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
    //...
    return rb;
}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
RichTextBox rb1 = RichTextBoxFactory();
RichTextBox rb2 = RichTextBoxFactory();
```

It can be benifitial to make it a class instead of a public function. That way you can call the function `Create()`, and you call it like this:

```
RichTextBox rb1 = RichTextBoxFactory.Create();
RichTextBox rb2 = RichTextBoxFactory.Create();
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly! Plus, now that I know how to do this, I can use it for all sorts of things.

Comment: Actually, although this does work perfectly to place controls on a form, I can't seem to access them from other methods. I tried creating a class version, but I keep getting errors about scope. I know these are rookie problems, but I am a complete rookie! Can you idiot-walk me through the steps to initialize the class? Thanks.